# How to exclude file types from SVN update

Tags: svn

I have a big repository full of data (images, videos, text files etc...) and while I want that all to go onto live server, I don't need to check that out for my testing environment (I'm fine without the videos).

Is there any way to exclude the video file types when checking out a working copy?

Currently I use a script that sets depth of folders that I know will have videos to empty, but that's not the perfect solution since those sometimes contain subfolders or poster images.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works:

```
$ svn co --depth=empty $REPO/branch/$proj
$ cd $proj
$ svn ls -R | while read $file
do
    [[ ${file%%*.} == ".mp4" ]] && continue   # Video or whatever
    if [[ ${file%%*/} != $file ]]             # Does file name end in a slash?
    then
        svn up --set-depth=empty "$file"      # Directory
    else
        svn up --set-depth=infinity "$file"   # File
    fi
done
```

However, this is excruciatingly slow since year `svn up` must go to the server, then wait for the update to take place, and do this for each and every file. There could also be an issue of names that contain whitespace although that wasn't a problem for me. I had a few files that contained one or two spaces that worked, but if a file contains two or more spaces together or a tab character, this might not work.

Give it a try, but I think your current method may be better. You can always use `svn ls -R` to find where videos do exist, and then prune via `--set-depth` (which can also include `exclude` as well as `immediates`, `empty`, and `infinity`).

What you should do is rearrange your repo, so that all the videos are in the same directory rather than scattered around. You'll have to change your JavaScript, HTML, and whatever other files you might have (PHP?) that access these file. This will make your work easier, and allow you to be a bit more flexible with your server. For example, you might want to mount your videos into a high speed access partition -- or at least its own partition, so you don't have 40 gigabytes of video on the same disk partition as the rest of your files.

Comment: Yeah, running `svn up` on every file might not be the perfect solution, but I'll definitely have a look at `svn ls -R`. If I come to some working solution I'll make sure to post it here.

Comment: It may be possible to build a list of files you want to do an update on, then pass them as a single argument (although you'd have to make sure you don't overrun the command line buffer). That may be quicker.